# Smoother way to type case a decimal

Tags: c#

I have an object of type `Entity` and according to watch facility it is of type "object {decimal}". I'm converting it using the code below but I'm not really happy about the approach (first stringification, then parsing).

```
double d = Double.Parse(entity["key"].ToString());
```

Is there a smoother, more recommended way to convert that value?

Comment: @MohsenAfshin, because this will throw an exception - `entity["key"]` is a `decimal` at runtime and `object` at compile-time.

Comment: @MohsenAfshin 1. I'm trying to **avoid** casting. 2. It's not going to compile. Sorry.

Comment: @MohsenAfshin I think the problem is that you haven't had the joy of working with `Entity` class yet. It's [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.entity%28v=vs.91%29.aspx). As soon as Microsoft hires me, I promise to give you the source code, hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to go with `double`, instead of `decimal` for two reasons. First of all, there's a slight difference in precision (meaning a slight cost in performance) as explained in [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5).

Secondly, check with the rest of your team. Since You were aiming for `double` to begin with, I'm making a wild guess that the value type that you're supposed to plug into the rest of your solution (especially since you mentioned Dynamics CRM) **is** in fact `double`.

In any case, one of the following lines will suffice (and is much nicer than type casting explicitly).

```
double dd  = Convert.ToDouble(entity["key"]);
decimal dc = Convert.ToDecimal(entity["key"]);
```

Comment: The increase in performance of a double is more than offset , by the amount of extra code you have to bolt round it to avoid it's inherent lack of accuracy. Can't say in this case but most just fall into using double, because it might be big and it's not an integer, it's just habit from when languages didn't have native support for double, so I wouldn't generally recommend it.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Fall into habit? What are you saying?! I always consider very carefully using this or that type for every project! (...ahem... not true ...hrmp... not true at all)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55.aspx) method:

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble(entity["key"]);
```

Also what's the point of using `decimal` as your data storage type and then casting it to `double`?

Comment: That's what I get back from my `QueryExpression` from the Dynamics CRM. Not much I can do about it. I'd prefer hard typing but that's not going to happen in this case... :)

Comment: My question is why do you need a `double`? Why not work with `decimal`?

Comment: Because I didn't think of it? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah mine too. Swap everything good about decimal, for everything bad about double. Doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I've always used `int` for wholes and `double` for fractions... I guess it's time to learn the old dog new natives.

Comment: Doubles have always been a PIA, I've dodged them with ints as well,. but decimal is a piece of nice, for most of fractional amounts us business type programmers use.